# Flutter The method 'showSnackBar' was called on null

Tags: flutter

I have a problem showing SnackBar. I tried GlobalKey, splitting widget to another class and also builder.

I get an exception which was discussed here more time

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'showSnackBar' was called on null.
```

But nothing solved my problem.

Here is my class

```
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = Provider.of<LoginProvider>(context);
    final bloc = Provider.of<LoginBloc>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: provider.loginStatus == LoginStatus.Authorizing
        ? Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              CircularProgressIndicator(),
              const Text('Signing in...')
            ],
          ),
        )
      : Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text(
                  Constants.loginButton,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  var loginValues = bloc.loginValues();
                  print(loginValues);
                  provider.signIn(loginValues).then(
                    (value) {
                      if (value != null) {
                        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                            context, MainScreen.routeName);
                      }
                    },
                  ).catchError(
                    (error) {
                      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(
                          content: Text(error.toString()),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
);
```

}
}

Showing SnackBar is executed in onCatch(). I found out that this same code works when my LoginScreen class is statefull widget not stateless. But I have no idea why.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

For Displaying snackbar under a scaffold:

1. Create a snackbar

```
final snackBar = SnackBar(
        content: Text(e.message),
      );
```

2. Displaying snackbar,

```
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

```
catchError((e) {
  final snackBar = SnackBar(
    content: Text(e.message),
  );
  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
});
```

**UPDATED:**

wrap your center widget with Builder widget and pass BuildContext

Comment: Do you know why his code works if the widget was stateful?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer but I know how to display snackbar... It's written in my question. The problem is that any of code showing snackbar doesn't work in Stateless widget in this particaular code. In Statefull works with no problem.

Comment: @Sam answer updated. this is because your widgets were not referring to Scaffold with Scaffold.of().

Comment: @SandeepSharma you can't do Scaffold.of() in widget that use context of build method inside which is Scaffold... This leads to exception... Only way to use this is to separate widget under Scaffold which is using this to standalone wiget, which I also written up that I tried.

Comment: Maybe put it the way, I know what I'm doing in Flutter, I'm not a beginner, I've done showing snackBar x times, but never faced this problem when done it this(or other 2 right) way